# jQuery animation sticking on quick hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

If you hover over the element slowly, the animation works correctly. The green layer overlaps from the left and then, from the top, the yellow layer overlaps the green layer. This overlapping should undo itself when the mouse leaves the element, starting with undoing the yellow overlap and then the green one.

But if the cursor hovers over it too quickly, the animation gets stuck on the yellow overlap until you re-mousover and then mouseout. I've tried adding `.stop(false, true)` jQuery method before each of the `.animate` methods, which is what I read has remedied similar problems but this didn't work. I tried it by chaining it right before the `.animate` function, I tried just about all variations of this, on all of the functions, and also with `.stop(true,true);`.

Is there a way I can stop the mouseout portion from firing if the mouseover portion doesn't finish before the cursor leaves the element?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#con').hover(
    function() { // handlerIn
      $('#crossX').animate({'width': '115px'}, function() {
        $('#crossY').animate({'height': '115px'})
      })
    },
    function() { // handlerOut
      $('#crossY').animate({'height': '15px'}, function() {
        $('#crossX').animate({'width': '15px'})
      })
    }
  )
});
```

```css
#con {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
  //background-color: black;
}
#one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color:black
}
#crossX {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:  green;
  color: yellow;
}
#crossY {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color:  yellow;
  color: white;
}
#black {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 15px solid black;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="con">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="crossX"></div>
  <div id="crossY"></div>
  <div id="black"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following solution it is guaranteed that the "mouse leave part" only runs after the "mouse enter part" is fullfilled and (vice versa).

Additionally the script takes care for the case that on quick user action: "enter > leave > enter" the state remains as if the user haven't done the "quick leave". **So actually this should do what you want to achieve** (I hope so at least).

```js
var mouseEnter = function() {
      // console.log('in');
      sPosition = 'in';
      if ( !mouseEnterIsDone || !mouseLeaveIsDone ) return mouseEnterIsWaiting = true;
      mouseEnterIsDone = false;
      $('#crossX').animate({'width':'115px'}, function(){
        $.when($('#crossY').animate({'height': '115px'})).then(function(){sanitizeAnimation('enter')})
      })
    },
    mouseLeave = function() {
      // console.log('out');
      sPosition = 'out';
      if ( !mouseEnterIsDone || !mouseLeaveIsDone ) return mouseLeaveIsWaiting = true;
      mouseLeaveIsDone = false;
      $('#crossY').animate({'height':'15px'}, function(){
        $.when($('#crossX').animate({'width': '15px'})).then(function(){sanitizeAnimation('leave')})
      })
    },
    sanitizeAnimation = function( sMode ){
      if ( 'enter' == sMode )
          mouseEnterIsDone = true;
      else
          mouseLeaveIsDone = true;
      if ( 'in' == sPosition ) {
        if ( mouseEnterIsWaiting ) {
          mouseEnterIsWaiting = false;
          mouseEnter();
        }
      } else {
        if ( mouseLeaveIsWaiting ) {
          mouseLeaveIsWaiting = false;
          mouseLeave();
        }
      }
    },
    mouseEnterIsDone = true,
    mouseLeaveIsDone = true,
    mouseEnterIsWaiting = false,
    mouseLeaveIsWaiting = false,
    sPosition = 'out';

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#con').hover(mouseEnter, mouseLeave);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5%;
}

#con {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
  //background-color: black;
}
#one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color:black
}
#crossX {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:  green;
  color: yellow;
}
#crossY {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color:  yellow;
  color: white;
}
#black {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 15px solid black;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="con">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="crossX"></div>
  <div id="crossY"></div>
  <div id="black"></div>
</div>
```

*If you need further explanations feel free to leave a comment*

Comment: Axel, thank you for your reply and explanation. Your solution makes the animation much better and does solve the problem that I asked. I'm now wondering if there is a way that the animation can retract from where it was left when the cursor leaves the element.

Comment: Yes @DustinL_G, that should be possible indeed. I recommend reading [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45885132/3931192) for getting a better understanding about animation with JS or CSS. You can ping me on a follow up question if you like...

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#con").mouseenter(function() {
$('body').addClass('Hover');
     $('#crossX').stop().animate({'width':'115px'},500, function(){
     $('#crossY').stop().animate({'height': '115px'},500);
     });
      
});

$("body").mouseenter(function() {
$('body').addClass('Hover');
      $('#crossY').stop().animate({'height':'0px'},500,function(){
      $('#crossX').stop().animate({'width':'0px'},500);
     });
      
});
```

```css
#con {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
  //background-color: black;
}
#one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color:black
}
#crossX {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:  green;
  color: yellow;
}
#crossY {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color:  yellow;
  color: white;
}
#black {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 15px solid black;
  z-index: 10;
}
body{
  background-color:#dcdcdc;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="con">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="crossX"></div>
  <div id="crossY"></div>
  <div id="black"></div>
</div>
</body>
```